# insert between two dates using array

Tags: mysql, arrays, date, insert, between

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO dat(empid,empname,reason,date)VALUES\n%s",  

 implode(",\n", $values) )

$query1= real_escape_string($query );
```

Please help me on abpove code . I cant insert character.

Comment: What is the value in $values variable?

Comment: Highly recommended to use prepared statement. Also you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition#920523

Comment: #archana   :  if i gave int to empid,empname,reason and date i can insert to db. if i use character to empid showing error like "Unknown column 'shyam' in 'field list".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **always** make sure that you data is safe.

```
    $emp_id_safe = filter_var($_POST['emp_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $emp_name_safe = filter_var($_POST['emp_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $reason_safe = filter_var($_POST['reason'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $end_date_safe = filter_var($_POST['to_date'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Secondly, the mysql PHP extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. Replace it with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

```
        if ($emp_id_safe == FALSE || $emp_name_safe == FALSE || 
            $reason_safe == FALSE || $end_date_safe == FALSE) {
            die('Filter failure');
        } else {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO date(empid, empname, reason, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $emp_id_safe, $emp_name_safe, $reason_safe, $end_date_safe);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Comment: #anna   Unknown column 'shyam' in 'field list' .( cant give character to empid.)

Comment: <?php
include("connect.php");
$start_date =$_POST['from_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['to_date'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$emp_name =$_POST['emp_name'];
$startTime = strtotime($start_date);
$endTime = strtotime($end_date);
$values = array();
for($time = $startTime; $time <= $endTime; $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time))
{  $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
   $values[] = "($emp_id, $emp_name, $reason,'$thisDate')";}
 $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO date(empid, empname, reason, date) VALUES (%s)", implode(",", $values));   
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error())?>